# Indexing pandas series with parent dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I wanted to run a function over each row of the pandas dataframe and output its value in the derived column score: The function shown below is a lambda for example but the function should be able to index by parent dataframe column labels and access column names like row['col1'] , but a series object is passed to the lambda function which loses the column label information:

eg:

```
def calculate(row):
    cols=row.columns
    loc=row['loc']
    h=row['h']
    isst=row['Ist']
    Hol=row['Hol']
    return loc+h+len(cols)

a['score']=a.apply(lambda row:calculate(row),axis=1)
```

gives:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'", u'occurred at index 0')
```

so how can I access a named series like a named tuple in the lambda function?

A quick hack would be to do:

```
a['score']=a.apply(lambda row:calculate(makedict(row,row.index)),axis=1)
```

where makedict function will create a dictionary for each row so that it can be accessed in the function by column labels. But is there an pandas way?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the to_dict  function which helps this:

```
def calculate(row):
    row=row.to_dict()
    loc=row['loc']
    h=row['h']
    isst=row['Ist']
    Hol=row['Hol']
    return loc+h+len(row.keys())

a['score']=a.apply(calculate,axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
a['score']=a.apply(lambda row:row['loc'] + row['h']+len(row.index),axis=1)
```

Comment: row becomes a series object hence column indexing not possible

Comment: A `DataFrame` has an index and columns. After extracting a row from the frame, it is a `Series`, which has an index, as above. The index for the new series will be identical to the columns in the DataFrame.